# Why can't I call jQuery methods on array elements in IE 11 or Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate an group of `<div>` elements using jQuery.animate.  But when I iterate an array the animate method is not defined on the element.
This works fine on chrome of course.

The array has a valid animate method, but each element does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" title="Standard" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var confettiPlayers = [];

    function makeItRain() {
        var confetti = $(".snow");//document.querySelectorAll('.snow');

        for (var i = 0, len = confetti.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var snowball = confetti[i];

            snowball.innerHTML = '<div class="rotate"><div class="askew"></div></div>';
            var scale = Math.random() * .8 + .2;

            // The next line throws exception on IE11/Edge
            // SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'animate'
            var player = snowball.animate([
                    { transform: 'translate3d(' + (i / len * 100) + 'vw,0,0) scale(' + scale + ')', opacity: scale },
                    { transform: 'translate3d(' + (i / len * 100 + 10) + 'vw,100vh,0) scale(' + scale + ')', opacity: 1 }
                ], {
                        duration: Math.random() * 3000 + 3000,
                        iterations: Infinity,
                        delay: -(Math.random() * 5000)
                    });


            confettiPlayers.push(player);

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        makeItRain();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="snowfall">
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
        <div class="snow"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested animate() on single elements and they work fine.

Comment: `snowball` is not a jQuery object, so it doesn’t have an `animate` method. Did you mean `$(snowball).animate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `var snowball = confetti[i];`:

`snowball` is an `HTMLElement` and not a `jQuery` object. There is an `HTMLElement` method `HTMLElement#animate` which is not supported in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

you need to use `var snowball = $(confetti[i]);` so that snowbal becomes a `jQuery` object instead of an `HTMLElement`

Comment: Doh!!  Thanks.  I didn't know that this wasn't supported on other browsers.

Comment: thought this was interesting so I made a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/ce6mkcy6/